# Read a series of images row by row or entire image for performance?

Tags: objective-c, performance, image

I'm writing an application that takes a series of exposures of a target and computes their average and saves the resultant image. This technique is used extensively in astrophotography to reduce noise in the final image. Basically, one computes the average at pixel and writes out the value in the output file.

The number of exposures can be quite high, from 20 to 30 (sometimes even more), and with today's large CCD sensors the resolution, too, can be quite high. So the amount of data can be very very large.

My question is, when it comes to performance, should I read the images row by row (Method #1) or should I read the entire image array of all arrays (Method #2)? Using the former method, I will have to load every corresponding row. So, if I have 10 images and I'm reading row #1 - I will have to read the first row from each image, compute their average and write out the row.

With the latter method, I read all images in their entirety, compute and write out the entire image.

In theory, the latter method ought to be much faster but much more memory intensive. In practice however, I've found that the difference in performance isn't great and this was puzzeling. At most, Method #2 was only 2 to 3 seconds faster than Method #1. However, Method #2 was using upto 1.3 GB of memory for 24 8megapixel images. Method #1, on the other hand, was at most using 70MB. On average, both methods are taking about 20 seconds to process 24 8megapixel images.

I am writing this in Objective-C with a good amount of C thrown in when calling CFITSIO.

Here's Method #1:

```
pixelRows = (double**)malloc(self.numberOfImages * sizeof(double*)); //alloc. pixel array.
for(i=0;i<self.numberOfImages;i++)
{
    pixelRows[i] = (double*)malloc(width*sizeof(double));
}
apix = (double*)malloc(width*sizeof(double));
for(firstpix[1]=1;firstpix[1]<=size[1];firstpix[1]++)
{
    [self gatherRowsFromImages:firstpix[1] withRowWidth:theWidth thePixelMap:pixelRows];
    [self averageRows:pixelRows width:width theAveragedRow:apix];
    fits_write_pix(outfptr, TDOUBLE, firstpix, width,apix, &status);
    //NSLog(@"Row %ld written.",firstpix[1]);
}

fits_close_file(outfptr,&status);
NSLog(@"End");
if(!status)
{
    NSLog(@"File written successfully.");
}
for(i=0;i<self.numberOfImages;i++)
{
    free(pixelRows[i]);
}
free(pixelRows);
free(apix);
```

Here's Method #2:

```
imageArray = (double**)malloc(files.count * sizeof(double*));
for(i=0;i<files.count;i++)
{
    imageArray[i] = (double*)malloc(size[0] * size[1] * sizeof(double));
    fits_read_pix(fptr[i],TDOUBLE,firstpix,size[0] * size[1],NULL,imageArray[i],NULL,&status);
    //NSLog(@"%d",status);
}
int fileIndex;

NSLog(@"%d",files.count);
apix = (double*)malloc(size[0] * size[1] * sizeof(double));
for(i=0;i<(size[0] * size[1]);i++)
{
    apix[i] = 0.0;
    for(fileIndex=0;fileIndex<files.count;fileIndex++)
    {
        apix[i] = apix[i] + imageArray[fileIndex][i];
    }
    //NSLog(@"%f",apix[i]);
    apix[i] = apix[i] / files.count;
}

fits_create_file(&outfptr,[outPath UTF8String],&status);
fits_copy_header(fptr[0],outfptr,&status);
fits_write_pix(outfptr, TDOUBLE, firstpix, size[0] * size[1],apix, &status);
fits_close_file(outfptr,&status);
```

Any suggestions regarding this? Am I expecting too much of a gain by reading in every image in its entirety?

Comment: Hi there. I'm working on a project where I need to be able to use cfitsio within objective-c and I'm having some trouble getting the library integrated in to an Xcode project. Do you think you could help me out since it sounds like you have done what I need to do? BTW It's an open source project I'm doing through UCSB. Thanks! My email is roxanne.brittain@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always go for the row-by-row approach, since it is scalable. It may also be faster since the memory footprint is smaller, meaning there is no need to swap out any program to disk just for your memory hungry tool.

Furthermore, to optimize the row-by-row approach, you should also consider reading in images per 8 rows (or some other number). E.g. JPEG is stored in 8x8 blocks, so reading in less than 8 rows would be pointless. Of course this depends on the image format and the library you are using.

There are also other considerations regarding the use of cache memory by the cpu. Memory locations that are used frequently don't have to travel to the "slow" memory but can stay closer to the cpu. There are several levels of cache and they vary in size per cpu type. (the biggest of which is typically 8 or 16 mb at the time of writing)

Another thing to consider is the code that does the actual averaging. Tuning this will also gain a lot, especially for the kind of operation you're doing, look at SSE and related topics. Also using integer calculations will probably beat floating point arithmetic. Using bit shifts for division might also be faster than true division, but it will only allow you to divide by 2^n.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I believe CFITSIO has some sort iterator function that automatically reads the optimal amount of blocks from the file. That should help, I think. Could you elaborate on what SSE is? Is it something that can be done on OS X and C/Objective-C?

Comment: But still, if you have 20 files you will be looping 20*8 times over the first 8 image rows while you could do it just in one pass per image. Function calls themselves form overhead. If you can just average a block of X bytes, it will be faster than averaging N lines times P pixels.

Comment: Google is your friend. SSE refers to a set of specialized cpu instructions found on Intel cpu's. AMD has its own set. They are typically useful to do operations on large blocks of memory. I presume there are libraries that you can use to exploit their magic. Otherwise you need to use inline assembly (which you really don't want).